# Mysql, cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

Why does this:

```
Create table Kaart (
aantal_geel     int         not null,
aantal_rood     int         not null,
Primary key (aantal_geel, aantal_rood));

Create table Wedstrijd (
datum           date        not null,
aantal_geel     int     not null,
aantal_rood     int     not null,   
Primary key (datum),
Foreign key (aantal_geel) REFERENCES kaart(aantal_geel),
Foreign key (aantal_rood) REFERENCES kaart(aantal_rood));
```

Gives: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the combination of the key columns, not each key column individually:

```
Create table Wedstrijd 
(
  datum           date    not null,
  aantal_geel     int     not null,
  aantal_rood     int     not null,   
  Primary key (datum),
  Foreign key (aantal_geel,aantal_rood) 
          REFERENCES kaart(aantal_geel,aantal_rood)
);
```

Comment: This actually didn't work, I think. Mysql did not make 'aantal_rood' bold in the object browser information. So only aantal_geel is set as a foreign key. But it didn't give any error. Is this a bug in Mysql or did it just not work?

Comment: @user2214897: works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a05b/1 I don't know what that "bold" thing in the object browser is, but it seems that this "object browser" is wrong. Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @user2214897: then it seems to be a "bug" in MySQL Workbench. My tool clearly shows the PK and FK constraints. Btw: J.W. solution is wrong as far as I can tell (see my comment there and the SQLFiddle to proof it)